# Invalid JSON RPC response on IOS build with Infura

Tags: web3js, tokens, web3-providers, ios

I am developing a mobile DAPP using ionic frame work, everything was fine when I testing on the browser. However I try to build my app on IOS, and run it on my Iphone7, the web3 doesn't work(did't have any action within the app), then I try to debug with the ionic dev app, and it show up an error with Invalid JSON RPC response. And I try to build as android app, and everything works. My ERC20 token contract was deployed on the Ropsten network.

[image]

My app information:

ionic 3.9.2

web3 1.0.0-beta.36

ethereumjs-tx 1.3.7

ethereumjs-util 6.0.0

provider: 'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/myapikey',

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
this.web3js = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(provider));
this.tokenContract = new this.web3js.eth.Contract(abi,contractAddress);
this.tokenContract.methods.balanceOf(myAddress).call().then(balance=>{console.log(balance);});
```

Does anyone face the same issue before?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Kristian No, not yet